# Is Python's monkey patching local to the current module?

Tags: python, gevent, monkeypatching

In a file a.py, I have the lines:

```
import gevent
gevent.monkey.patch_all()

import b
# etc, etc
```

In file b.py is it necessary to monkey patch again? Is there anything wrong with monkey patching multiple times?

Comment: I'm no expert on `gevent`, but I can't see any way that it wouldn't be "global" ... e.g. I can't see any way that calls in `b` wouldn't behave like the monkey patched versions in `a`.  As far as problems with monkey patching multiple times, that's probably safe, but I guess it would depend on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there's just one entry in `sys.modules` for each module. ie, the same module object is shares, so it affects the module as long as it's imported the same way.

It's possible to have the same module in `sys.modules` under two or more entries if it is imported differently.

Comment: I don't think I understand you fully. For example, `socket` is monkey patched by gevent. So if the `a.py` has `import socket` and `b.py` has `from socket import *`, the effect would be different? `b.py` won't be monkey patched?

Comment: @donatello It depends on *when* the patching is done and when the imports are done. If the patching is done *before* the imports, then all imports are affected, but if the imports happen before the patching, then `a.py` *might* have a patched module while `b` will still use the original functions etc.(due to the star import). I don't know how `gevent` does the patching, so `a` may or may not use the patched version depending on whether `gevent` replaces the module object or changes its attributes.